# Empty is not equal to False in Data Extension?

Tags: journeybuilder, dataextensions

I launched a journey today based on a Data Extension that had a column called Sent_1st_Email.

Out of the 18K leads, there were about 2300 who had that column marked as True. The remaining records had Sent_1st_Email=Empty.

My assumption was that Empty boolean values also equals False, but this doesn't appear to be the case because in my journey I stated in a decision split: IF Sent_1st_Email = False THEN send Email1. All records skipped this and went to Email2.

Can someone confirm whether I'm correct in my thinking here or could there be something wrong with my journey?

Comment: As far as I know empty doesn't mean false but you can avoid it by setting "False" as default. Then, empty means false for you.

Answer (score 0):

An empty or null value **does not equal** a false boolean value.